# Usar ajax para llenar child row de Datatable con json en formato Simple array of data

Tags: ajax, json, datatables, codeigniter-3

¿Como puedo hacer para poblar mi tabla con dos ajax a la vez y de que manera debo llamar los datos(Json)? [Ejemplo](https://datatables.net/blog/2017-03-31#Basic-DataTable)

Estoy trabajando en codeigniter y el problema es que al crear mi Json me regresa un  [arreglo simple](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax):

```
[
{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
},
...
```

}

Asi que para poblar mi tabla debo llamarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
 var table = $('#t2').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/reporteJson/getReporteAllJson",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
columns: [
    {
        className:      'details-control',
        orderable:      false,
        data:           null,
        defaultContent: ''
    },

        { "data": "CCODIGOCLIENTE" },
        { "data": "CRAZONSOCIAL" },
        { "data": "PENDIENTE" },
        { "data": "veintiunov" },
        { "data": "catorcev" },
        { "data": "sietev" },
        { "data": "siete" },
        { "data": "catorce" },
        { "data": "veintiuno" },
        { "data": "mes" },
        { "data": "bimestre" },
        { "data": "trimestre" }
],
order: [[1, 'asc']]
```

} );

Hasta ahi si funciona, pero necesito una segunda consulta (Json) que me permita poblar chilrows para cada dato, probe esto:

```
$('#t2 tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var row = table.row( tr );

if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
}
else {
    row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
}
```

} );

```
function format ( rowData ) {
    var div = $('<div/>')
        .addClass( 'loading' )
        .text( 'Loading...' );

    $.ajax( {
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/reporteJson/getReporteAll',
        dataSrc: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function ( json ) {
            div
                .html( json.html )
                .removeClass( 'loading' );
        }
    } );

    return div;
}
```

pero lo unico que muestra son los datos de la tabla y al momento de querer visualizar los childrows solo muestra que se esta cargando... ¿Alguna solucion o idea de porque pasa esto?

[MI CODIGO](http://live.datatables.net/letezozu/4/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

```
Me tomo bastantte tiempo encontrar la solucion a esto porque casi no habia info en linea, asi que espero que mi respuesta ayude a algun programador solitario...

Primer paso, estoy desarrollando en codeigniter asi que lo primero fue resolver que me devolviera un Json data Object, en lugar de un Flat Array

    public function MiConsultaObject(){
        $data['data'] = $this->modelo_con_consulta_flat_array->MiConsultaFlatArray();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

Segundo paso, crear mi tabla en Html, asegurandome de dejar una columna libre para el btn de childRow (en < td >, se imprimiran los detalles de la subconsulta por id)


       <div class="row">
                 <table id="miTabla" class="display" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>col2</th>
                            <th>col3</th>
                            <th>col4</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="details-control"></td> 
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>col2</th>
                            <th>col3</th>
                            <th>col4</th>
                        </tr>
                        <br>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>

Tercer paso, llamar la consulta por ajax

    var table = $('#miTabla').DataTable( {
    ajax: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controlador/MiConsultaObject',
        dataType:"",
   columns: [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "ID" },
            { "data": "Col2" },
            { "data": "Col3" },
            { "data": "Col4" }
        ],
    order: [[1, 'asc']]
} );

Paso cuatro, crea la accion de despliegue de detalles:


  $('#miTabla tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );

Paso cinco, crea la funcion de cargando... y  llama al childrow correspondiente seguin el id


function format ( rowData ) {
    var div = $('<div/>')
        .addClass( 'loading' )
        .text( 'Loading...' );

    $.ajax( {
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controlador/VistaConTablaDeSubconsulta',
        type:"post",
        data: {
            ID: rowData.ID
        },
        dataType:"html",
        success: function ( json ) {

            div
                .html(json
                  )
                .removeClass( 'loading' );
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
         alert('Exception:', exception);
        }
    } );

    return div;
}


Paso Seis, crear VistaConTablaDeSubconsulta

    <div style="overflow-x: auto; ">
     <table id="TablaDeSubconsulta" class="display nowrap table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%; ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php foreach ($detallesTablaDeSubconsulta as $c): ?>  
            <tr>
                <td ><?php echo  $c->ID;?></td>
                <td ><?php echo  $c->ID;?></td>
                <td ><?php echo  $c->ID;?></td>
                <td ><?php echo  $c->ID;?></td>
            </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>






 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#TablaDeSubconsulta').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true
        },

} );



*En la consulta $detallesTablaDeSubconsulta debe pasarse directamente el ID como parametro $ID
```

Suerte!!